# Object doesn't support this property or method: 'eof' on recordset opened from xml

Tags: c#, xml, asp-classic, recordset

I am calling some xml from a .net webservice and want to turn it back into a recordset so I can use it with a classic asp website. 
Everything goes smoothly until I I go

```
 do until rs.eof
```

and then I get the above error.

My code calling the webservice:

```
 Dim xmlhttp
    Dim postUrl
    postUrl = "http://localhost:9065/Interrogator.asmx/TestRecordSet"

    Set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.Open "POST",postUrl,false
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xmlhttp.send()
    xml =xmlhttp.responseText
    set dom = server.createobject("microsoft.xmldom")
    dom.loadXML(xml)
   ''# get the actual value
    set node = dom.selectsinglenode("//string")
    rs= RecordsetFromXMLString(node.text)
      do until rs.eof <---- ERROR HERE
            response.Write(rs("ID"))
      rs.movenext : loop
```

My code converting the xml to a record set:

```
    Public Function RecordsetFromXMLString(sXML)

    Dim oStream
    Set oStream = server.createobject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Charset = "iso-8859-1"
    oStream.Open
    oStream.WriteText sXML   ''# Give the XML string to the ADO Stream
    oStream.Position = 0    ''# Set the stream position to the start    
    Dim oRecordset
    Set oRecordset = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")       
    oRecordset.Open oStream    ''# Open a recordset from the stream
    oStream.Close
    Set oStream = Nothing
    Set RecordsetFromXMLString = oRecordset  ''# Return the recordset
    Set oRecordset = Nothing
End Function
```

My Xml is this:

```
    <xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
    xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
    <s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:updatable='true'>
        <s:AttributeType name='ID' rs:number='1' rs:write='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='0'
             rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Name' rs:number='2' rs:write='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='1000'
             rs:precision='0' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='SomethingElse' rs:number='3'
             rs:write='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='1000'
             rs:precision='0' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
    </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
    <rs:insert>
        <z:row ID='1'/>
        <z:row Name='Name0'/>
        <z:row Name='blah blah0'/>
        <z:row ID='2'/>
        <z:row Name='Name1'/>
        <z:row Name='blah blah1'/>

    </rs:insert>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

I think it's something to do with needing an disconnected recordset but I have tried adding

```
    oRecordset .LockType =adLockBatchOptimistic
oRecordset .CursorLocation = adUseClient
```

As I did on the .net side but it won't except it! I may be totally wrong as I am a c# .net developer, most definitely not classic asp and I am finding this difficult.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to make rs an object, try this:

```
set rs= RecordsetFromXMLString(node.text)
```